# File not found when building a Web Deployment Project

Tags: asp.net, web-deployment-project

I've got a web deployment project that builds and zips a web application project. I am getting a lot of errors when I build the WDP, as follows:

> Error 73  The file '/Foo.csproj/Properties/Administration/Modules/ACL.ascx' does not exist.   /Foo.csproj/Properties/Administration/ACL.aspx
>
> Error 74  Unknown server tag 'foo:ACL'.   /Foo.csproj/Properties/Administration/ACL.aspx

These errors are coming from the Web Deployment Project, not the WAP.
The errors always follow the same pattern, first there is an error finding the .ascx and then an associated error saying the server tag related to the previous ascx is unknown (this obviously makes sense).

There are no errors or warnings in the ascx or aspx.

The controls are registered using a `<%@ Register %>` tag (as opposed to being registered in the web.config)

**What could be causing such a symptom?**

---

**UPDATE**

The errors are coming from `aspnet_compiler.exe` which is run with the following command:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_compiler.exe -v "/Foo.csproj" -p "C:\Projects\Foo\Foo" -u -f -d obj\Staging\TempBuildDir

and produces the following errors

> Utility to precompile an ASP.NET application
>    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>   /Foo.csproj/Properties/Administration/ACL.aspx(5): error ASPPARSE: The file '/Foo.csproj/Properties/Administration/Modules/ACL.ascx' does not exist.
>   /Foo.csproj/Properties/Administration/ACL.aspx(7): error ASPPARSE: Unknown server tag 'foo:ACL'.

in Foo.csproj ACL.aspx is declared as

```
<Content Include="Administration\ACL.aspx" />

<!-- Snip -->

<Compile Include="Administration\ACL.aspx.cs">
  <DependentUpon>ACL.aspx</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Administration\ACL.aspx.designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>ACL.aspx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

and ACL.ascx as

```
<Content Include="Administration\Modules\ACL.ascx" />

<!-- Snip -->

<Compile Include="Administration\Modules\ACL.ascx.cs">
  <DependentUpon>ACL.ascx</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Administration\Modules\ACL.ascx.designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>ACL.ascx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

I can't understand where the `/Properties/` element of the paths is coming from in the paths in the error ! It's not in project file and it's not being fed to `aspnet_compiler.exe`.

The solution file and project files are identical (apart from project names) to a working solution.

Answer (score 14):

I just came across this same situation in a project at my desk, and here was my solution:

```
//doesn't work
<%@ Control Language="C#" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" 
    Inherits="Controls_CatalogCustomerORW"
    CodeFile="CatalogCustomerORW.ascx.cs" %>

//does work
<%@ Control Language="C#" 
    AutoEventWireup="true"
    Inherits="Controls_CatalogCustomer" 
    Codebehind="CatalogCustomer.ascx.cs" %>
```

The error appears to be the ever subtle `CodeFile` vs `CodeBehind`

Answer (score 2):

I've seen something *similar* to this (my recollection is admittedly a bit hazy!) when the "Build Action" for the file is set to `None` rather than `Content`. To see if this is the issue:

1. Right-click on the file that's at issue, in Solution Explorer, and choose `Properties`
2. Look at the "Build Action" for the file, if it says `None` correct it to `Content`.

The other possibility is that something has gone "wrong" in your `.csproj` as the path to ACL.ascx looks decidedly odd. Should it *really* be under `/Foo.csproj/Properties/`? If my first suggestion isn't helpful, I'd suggest trying the following:

1. Right-click on `Foo.csproj` in Solution Explorer and choose `Unload Project`
2. Once it's finished unloading, right-click on `Foo.csproj (Unavailable)` in Solution Explorer and choose `Edit Foo.csproj`
3. Search for `ACL.ascx` and compare the XML markup for that file to another "good" file that isn't generating the error, there' likely a subtle difference there which is causing the error

Comment: yep, the .../Properties/... does look weird but I can't see such a path in any of my project files. I'll keep digging. Cheers for the thoughts

Answer (score 2):

I was getting a similar error.

My situation was the following:

```
root/page.aspx
root/page.aspx.cs
root/page.aspx.designer.cs
root/X/page.aspx
```

for some reason someone copied the page.aspx file to the X folder, and even removing the file from my web application project, the deployment project was still having problems. I also noticed that even with a different name (e.g. copy of page.aspx in the x folder, the problem would still arise).

It only worked when I deleted the file page.aspx (or whatever name it had) from X folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have resolved the problem by deleting the `CodeFile="MyFile.aspx.cs"` attribute from the `MyFile.aspx` file. I think the error happens because of the `CodeFile` attribute has greater priority over the value `<SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>` in `MyProject.csproj`.